# What is the meaning of the word Hastinapur?

Tags: mahabharata, sanskrit, etymology, kauravas

The city Hastinapur from the Mahabharata is where the Kauravas reside. What is the meaning for this word? Is there any source for it?

Answer (score 1):

"Hastinapur" is a Sanskrit word that originates from ancient Indian literature and mythology. It refers to a legendary city mentioned in the Indian epic, the Mahabharata. The name is derived from "Hasti," which means elephant, and "pura," which means city. So, "Hastinapur" can be translated as the "City of Elephants."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).